How to add to my GitHub page an html page which comes from another repository of mine?
I created a GitHub page following the instructions and it is published under GitHub Pages as example.github.io.
Now I would like to add to this page the HTML pages of my projects, which are stored in other repositories different from the one where the page is stored. For example, I would like to add my_project.html which is stored in my_repo.
To this aim, I would prefer

not to add the projects to GitHub Pages as suggested in this answer or here
not to clone the whole project repository in the GitHub page repository as suggested here
not to use the htmlpreview.github.io/
not to copy-paste the HTML file into the example.github.io repository (because if I update the project, it will not be updated on example.github.io)

Is there a way to, for example, clone the single html file my_project.html from the my_repo repository to the example.github.io one?
Or to directly link to the HTML page?
Please, notice also that I am relatively new to GitHub and I use it through the browser interface.
I already made all the naive attempts like adding a link to https://example.github.io/my_user/my_repo/blob/main/my_project.html, to https://example.github.io/my_user/my_repo/my_project.html, etc., but I am well aware they will not work if the html file I want is not contained in the same repository as the index.html.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

@DarkBee the question is unrelated to the specific content of the website, it's about github pages. I don't think the links are necessary but they're not replacing any important details that should be in the question itself

Can't see how the contents of the repo is relevant to the question? The question already received two answers. I've removed the URL's and added an explanation why I've edited out the links

You can use GitHub Actions to deploy your project to GitHub Pages, and download the files with a script before deploying the project :
workflow.yml :
jobs:
  deploy:
    # Grant GITHUB_TOKEN the permissions required to make a Pages deployment
    permissions:
      pages: write      # to deploy to Pages
      id-token: write   # to verify the deployment originates from an appropriate source

# Deploy to the github-pages environment
environment:
  name: github-pages
  url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}

# Specify runner + deployment step
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:

  - uses: actions/checkout@v4

  - name: Download files
    run: |
         wget https://github.com/paolosaracco/MTG-TopRankedDecks/blob/81498093c5b6d3cfd1c6767f34d98902a9f2488b/MtG_project.html
         wget https://github.com/paolosaracco/MTG-TopRankedDecks/blob/*************/MtG_project.html
         # etc
         
  - name: Upload pages artifact
    uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
    with:
      path: / # Where all the static files are located

  - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
    id: deployment
    uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

You can find more documentation here to deploy with a workflow : https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-with-a-custom-github-actions-workflow

Thanks, but may I ask a few more questions? (1) I suppose I need to store the workflow.yml file in a .github/workflows folder in the repo containing the webpage, don't I? (2) Apparently, this script produces and artifact called "github-pages.zip" (which I suppose contains the webpage), but then how can I link/access/deploy the content of this artifact? I mean, how can I create in the index.html a link to the webpage with the project?

If you want to reference the files from index.html, you'll have to create the links before downloading the files. And yes you''ll have to store the workflow in this folder. If you look at the previous deployments in your repo, you'll see that Jekyll is used to build your site and that it creates a "./_site" folder with your code. Download your html files with wget, move them in this folder (I think you can rename them with the "mv" command and give them the names of the links in your index.html file. Then upload the ./site folder as an artifact and deploy it.

Thanks a lot. At the end my problem was exactly that I forgot to switch the Source from "Deploy from a branch" to "GitHub Actions" under "Build and deployment" and so pages-build-deployment was overwriting the site deployed by workflow, I suppose.

You're welcome, forgot to mention that, by default it's always published by a branch when you enable Pages. Also you can host other projects on Pages, they'll be deployed on a url like this : ${username}.github.ui/${project_name}

You can do this using git submodules, where you add the MTG-TopRankedDecks as a submodule of the main github pages repository. This would create a directory (you could call it MTG-TopRankedDecks) that is linked to the other repository and will include your HTML file.
It won't automatically update to the latest submodule version (I.e. commits to MTG-TopRankedDecks would have to be "pulled" in your GH pages repository), but you could use a Github Actions workflow to automate that.
You'll also have to resolve a a quirk relating to the github actions workflow to make the deployment, instructions for that are on this discussion post: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/66112
